# Diferencia entre asp:Textbox e Input type="text"

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Tengo unos meses trabajando con ASP.NET y me ha surgido una duda derivada de un nuevo formulario que estoy generando.

Vengo usando `input type="text" class="mach-form-control"/>` para agregar Textbox y así he estado haciendo algunos ejemplos para seguir practicando.

Lo hago también con input `type=text` porque al revisar algunos formularios de ejemplo, es lo que se ha usado para esos desarrollos, entonces pensé que esto era el "así debe hacerse".

Hoy se me ocurrió usar objetos del Cuadro De Herramientas (estoy programando en Visual Studio 2022) y al arrastrar un textbox, y revisar el código, se genera la siguiente linea.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Mi duda es precisamente cual es la diferencia entre usar input `type=Text`, a usar `asp:textbox`.

Answer (score 0):

`asp:Textbox` es un control del lado del Servidor de asp.net, donde `asp` se refiere al espacio de nombre (*name space*) y `Textbox` es el tipo de control.

Por el contrario el `<input>` es un elemento nativo de HTML

Primero hay que entender la motivación de todo: Microsoft contaba con una tecnologia muy exitosa en programas de escritorio basada en formularios, primero con Visual Basic (sobre todo la versión 6) y luego con lo que llamó "WinForms", y en lo referente a web tenia ASP (clásico) el cual no era tan popular.

Cuando las aplicaciones web comenzaron a ser moda, la respuesta de Microsoft fue asp.net con la tecnología que llamó "WebForms". La idea era captar a los desarrolladores provenientes de "WinForms", brindándoles una forma similar a como venían trabajando.

###### (A modo personal: Se cometieron muchos errores con esta tecnología, hoy al 2023 no conviene en nada su uso)

Para lograr esto, Microsoft recurrió a variadas técnicas y básicamente trucos. Una de ellas fueron los componentes del lado del Servidor.

Un componente del lado del servidor tiene propiedades, eventos y métodos, de manera muy similar a los componentes "WinForms"

Por ejemplo, en WinForms el elemento "Textbox" tiene la propiedad `Visible` al igual que su símil en WebForms

En WinForms el texboxt tiene una propiedad llamada `MultiLine`, en WebForms hubo un pequeño cambio y se llamó `TextMode` cuyos valores pueden ser `SingleLine`,`MultiLine` o `Password`

Y aquí tienes, la que creo yo, es la principal diferencia con el `<input>` de HTML.

En HTML tienes `<input type="text>` para los textos de una línea y `<textarea>` que es un elemento distinto para textos multilínea, en cambio en ASP.NET es solo una propiedad la que cambia el comportamiento.

Pero tampoco hay magia en el asunto. El navegador envía una petición al servidor y el servidor renderiza todos estos componentes a HTML valido, por ejemplo devolviendo un `<input type="text>` o un `<textarea>` según sea el caso.

Además un control de lado del servidor tiene los mecanismos necesarios para almacenar el estado en el `viewstate`, tienen un ciclo de vida con gatillamiento de eventos los cuales puedes escuchar en el `code behind`

---

En síntesis `<asp:Textbox>` es un control del lado del servidor, que cuenta con propiedades y eventos que "facilitan" la programación y este puede (o no) ser renderizado como un `<input type="text">`, el cual es un elemento nativo de HTML